# Разместить строку после текста

Tags: css3, html5, позиционирование

Как поместить стоку с кнопками "Train Dev Test"после абзаца текста?

На данный момент страница выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.text p {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 216px;
  top: 223px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 200px;

}

.button1 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 29px 100px 60px;
}

.button2 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 515px;
  top: 554px;
}

.button3 {
  background: #8953FC;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 199px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 816px;
  top: 554px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="offer">
    <h1 class="title">Задания</h1>
    <div class="text">
      <p class="p1">
  1.RuMedDaNet <br>
  <br>Основная цель этой задачи — измерить способность модели "понимать" медицинский текст и правильно отвечать на уточняющие вопросы.
      Истинная медицинская модель искусственного интеллекта должна обладать всесторонними знаниями и "пониманием" различных областей, связанных со здоровьем. Частично такие способности можно проверить, оценив ответы модели на контекстно-зависимые вопросы.
      Пример задания состоит из контекста и связанного с ним бинарного вопроса. Цель модели правильно ответить на поставленный вопрос либо да, либо нет.
      Контексты собраны из широкого набора областей, связанных с медициной: терапия, физиология и анатомия человека, фармакология, биохимия и т.п. Вопросы сгенерированы и размечены асессорами.
      Выборка разбита на 3 части train/dev/test, содержащие 1308/256/512 примеров.
      Для оценки результатов используется метрика Accuracy.</p>
    
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="button1" href="#">Train</a>
  <a class="button2" href="#">Dev</a>
  <a class="button3" href="#">Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Можете прикрепить html код? А то так не понятно

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev код добавлен

Comment: HTML, а не только CSS. И код добавляйте пожалуйста текстом, а не изображениями.

Comment: @Simon строки с кодами добавила текстом

Answer (score 0):

```
         <div class="offer">
        <h1 class="title">Задания</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <p class="p1">
1.RuMedDaNet <br>
<br>Основная цель этой задачи — измерить способность модели "понимать" медицинский текст и правильно отвечать на уточняющие вопросы.
Истинная медицинская модель искусственного интеллекта должна обладать всесторонними знаниями и "пониманием" различных областей, связанных со здоровьем. Частично такие способности можно проверить, оценив ответы модели на контекстно-зависимые вопросы.
Пример задания состоит из контекста и связанного с ним бинарного вопроса. Цель модели правильно ответить на поставленный вопрос либо да, либо нет.
Контексты собраны из широкого набора областей, связанных с медициной: терапия, физиология и анатомия человека, фармакология, биохимия и т.п. Вопросы сгенерированы и размечены асессорами.
Выборка разбита на 3 части train/dev/test, содержащие 1308/256/512 примеров.
Для оценки результатов используется метрика Accuracy.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Ты забыл закрыть блоки с текстом, то есть отделить и по этому твои ссылки в одном блоке с текстом.